# PHP form to search data in MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql

I try to open this post to receive some help about a problem with a search form that doesn't work correctly.

I have a MySQL DB with some data stored in different tables:

DB is: list_pec
Table are: pec_1, pec_2, pec_3 and pec_4

All of these tables contain the same rows with different data. Rows are
firstame, lastname, email, id_client, id_2client

My goal is to create a search form in PHP in which there are an input label and a selection form that is used to connect to the database and give me as an output query result.

Below PHP file to connect MySQL DB that I called "conn.php"

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$userName = "demo";
$password = "demo";
$dbName = "list_pec";

// Create database connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $userName, $password, $dbName);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

below file called "search.php" in which there's form and php code, obv i want have query result in the same .php file so i used `<?pho echo $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF']; ?>` in form action

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include("conn.php");

$search_output = "";
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    if($_POST['option']== "a"){
     $sqlcommand="SELECT email, id_client, id_2client FROM pec_1 WHERE email = 'email'";
     }

     else if ($_POST['option'] == "b"){
     $sqlcommand="SELECT email, id_client, id_2client FROM pec_2 WHERE email = 'email'";
     }

     else if ($_POST['option'] == "c"){
     $sqlcommand="SELECT email, id_client, id_2client FROM pec_3 WHERE email = 'email'";
     }

          else if ($_POST['option'] == "d"){
     $sqlcommand="SELECT email, id_client, id_2client FROM pec_4 WHERE email = 'email'";
     }



$query = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlcommand) or die (mysqli_error($conn));
$search_output .="<hr />query result: ";
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $email = $row ["email"];
    $pec = $row ["id_client"];
    $sdi = $row ["id_2client"];
    $search_output .= "<hr/><p> $email - $id_client - $id_2client</p>";


} else{
    $search_output= "<hr /> No Result";

}
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Search id_client and id_2client</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row my-5">
                <h1>Search id_client and id_2client</h1>
            </div>
<form name="ricerca-pec" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER ['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Inserisci l'email del cliente</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="youremail@email.com" name="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select Option</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" name="option">
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
      <option value="c">C</option>
      <option value="d">D</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit"></input>
</form>

</div>
</section>

<section>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<p><?php echo $search_output; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
</section>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQx"</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I use search form ( going on file /search.php ) I have an answer "No result", so I saw that query is executed correctly, but it to seem that variable 'email' isn't sent from $_POST on form submit to query.

In effect, if I modify in search.php file this first query replacing to 'email' with 'email@email.com' ( that is contained in table DB pec_1 ) I can see as a right result from the query

```
     $sqlcommand="SELECT email, id_client, id_2client FROM pec_1 WHERE email = 'email@email.com'";
```

Please, I ask some help to understand the problem and solve, I read other posts without solving my problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot fetch any email, it is because you passed it in plain in your `$sqlCommand`. For example:

```
$sqlcommand="SELECT email, id_client, id_2client FROM pec_4 WHERE email = 'email'";
```

should be more like:

```
$sqlcommand="SELECT email, id_client, id_2client FROM pec_4 WHERE email = {$email}";
```

But you have not defined any email variable yet, so it won't work. Your code is quite confusing and has some security issues. I gave you some hints as comments on your PHP part to make it working better.

```
<?php

// Require only once the connection to avoid multiples connexions
require_once('conn.php');

// Debug here
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$search_output = "";
// Check if the form has been sent
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){

    // Define variables
    $table = '';
    $option = '';
    $email = '';

    // Check if an option is selected
    if(!isset($_POST["option"])) {
        // ToDo: Security - check user input
        $option = $_POST["option"];
    } else {
        // Throw error to the user
    }

    // Check if a email is set
    if(!isset($_POST["email"])) {
        // ToDo: Security - check user input
        $email = $_POST["email"];
    } else {
        // Throw error to the user
    }

    // Use a switch instead of plenty if
    switch ($option) {
        case "a":
            $table = "pec_1";
        break;
        case "b":
            $table = "pec_2";
        break;
        case "c":
            $table = "pec_3";
        break;
        case "d":
            $table = "pec_4";
        break;
        default:
            $table = "pec_1";
        break;
    }

    // write your query once
    $selectQuery = "SELECT email, id_client, id_2client FROM {$table} WHERE email LIKE %{$email}%";
    // Perform your query
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $selectQuery);
    // Fetch the result as array
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

    $search_output .="<hr />query result: ";

    // If no results
    if(count($results) < 1) {
        $search_output= "<hr /> No Result";
    } else {
        $email = $result["email"];
        $pec = $result["id_client"];
        $sdi = $result["id_2client"];
        $search_output .= "<hr/><p> {$email} - {$pec} - {$sdi}</p>";
    }

}
?>
```

To also reply about your form question, when the script is in the same page a simple `action="/"` attribute is enough to reload the same page.

Comment: Hi i changed my code as you have suggest me but i  have other problems now

1) I can see as output two "else" conditions that i inserted in my search.php file

// Check if an option is selected } else {  echo 'something'; }
// Check if a email is set } else { echo 'something';  }

2) other error 
 Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /search.php on line 56

that is   $result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

3) other error

 Notice: Undefined variable: results in /search.php on line 61

that is   if(count($results) < 1) {

Comment: I solved all, understanding better my code, php necessity i declared variables before function and then declare it again with = $_POST['email'] and = $_POST['option]. in it to solve. Thank you.